# Error during the communication on a msg queue

Tags: c, linux, unix, msg, msgrcv

I made a message queue, but when assistant send the message to his client, the client received wrong number: -1081388352. This is for every number I send.
There is no error during the msgget and even durign msgcrv or msgsnd.
The code for the send:

```
key_t chiave_ac = ftok("prenotazione.c", 'M');
    if(chiave_ac == -1){
        perror("ftock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int coda_ac = msgget(chiave_ac, IPC_CREAT | 0642);
    if(coda_ac == -1){
        perror("msgget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

if (msgsnd(coda_ac, &m, sizeof(messaggio)-sizeof(long), 0) == -1) {
            perror("msgsnd");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Recivied:

```
key_t chiave_ac = ftok("prenotazione.c", 'M');
    if(chiave_ac == -1){
        printf("Errore nel generare la chiaveAC \n");
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }
    int id_ac  = msgget(chiave_ac, 0);
    if (id_ac == -1){
        perror("msgget ac");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
if( msgrcv(id_ac, &risp, sizeof(messaggio)-sizeof(long), getpid(), 0) == -1){
                    printf("errore ricezione \n");
                    fflush(stdout);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? There's an error in some flag?

---

[added from comment:]

```
typedef struct
{
  long type; 
  int pid; 
  scelta tipo; 
  int aula; 
  int giorno; 
  bool finito; 
} messaggio;
```

Comment: You might like to show us the definition and initialisation of `m`, `risp` as well as the definition  of `messaggio`.

Comment: typedef struct{
 long type;
 int pid;  
 scelta tipo;  
 int aula;      
 int giorno;      
 bool finito;   
} messaggio;

Comment: "*the client received wrong number*" which member of `messaggio` are you refering to? Which value are you sending? How do you set it in the sender? How do you inspect, print, show, read it in the receiver?

Comment: He received wrong number only in the memember aula and giorno. The others are ok. I make a logfile. I use semaphores, may this could be the problem?